# How to force blur without calling onBlur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I force blurring, but without calling onBlur event in JavaScript/jQuery?

I'll try to describe you what I need it for:

- when onBlur is called, I call a PHP script via jQuery and validating input. If there's something wrong, it returns a message and then I display it back in jQuery script.
- if a blurred field isn't filled, script should focus user back to that field.

And the problem is that if you press TAB to change field, and your first field is not filled, script will focus you back, but then is called onBlur from second field that is also not filled, and then it causes an infinite loop.

So, i want to blur a field and focus to another without calling onBlur event.

Comment: Why not use `change`? And also run the validation on the `submit` event.

Comment: Please don't force the focus back to the field the user is trying to leave, that is _so_ annoying. When the user tries to submit it's OK to move the focus back to the problem field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an answer as spec'ed in your question, but what I'd suggest you do (in a somewhat UX sort of perspective) is to scrap the auto-refocus on invalid input, and instead mark the invalid field (may I suggest red, for example?). Now, you can go and deal with the (arguably) simpler problem of preventing a form submit on invalid data, instead of the problem of preventing a *natural browser behavior* type of an event.

Additionally, I'd dare to say that auto-refocusing is **irritating** for the user. Imagine tabbing to the second field, start typing, then suddenly *yoink!* You get dragged to the first field.

Comment: Not only is auto-refocusing irritating for the user, but cross-browser implementation is really difficult to achieve with this design because of the way that blur and focus bubble in devices like iOS5 and Andriod 2.2. you'll notice that (now a days, anyway) corporate and enterprise websites use the method that you explain, rather than a re-focus. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use on "change" and "keyup" instead of on blur?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Richard above, there's nothing more annoying than losing focus in the middle of typing, but if you do need to do this (Due to a customer requirement etc) - in the code that auto-focuses the field, disable the `onBlur` function temporarily until you've focused the field, then re-enable it.

Comment: Yeah someone downed mine immediately too. With no comment. I upped yours since it's not a bad idea. Someone's trolling...

Comment: @Jan ~ I mentioned this in another question just last week, actually, but I did notice the *instant* downvotes more rampant these past few weeks.